# How to access window or root view controller from CocoaTouch framework?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I wrote simple CocoaTouch framework, and I want to add UIPickerView in bottom of view but my view is small and no specific position and when I addsubview UIPickerview, it's show but not work. When UIPicker inside my view it's work.

I thought if I add UIPickerView on root view my problem solved, but  I can't access to root view or window on my framework:

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared
<UIApplication: 0x7ff756e00e70>


(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.windows
0 elements


(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
nil
```

[image: picker view outside of my view]

My framework available on GitHub AZViewer on develop branch.
and my problem on example project commit : `697eb35`

Comment: Please don't post a link to your project. [Edit] your question to include relevant code as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

When you call and create instance of your class in your framework or your project in `viewDidLoad` and then your this instance want to access the root window, `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` return `nil` because the view controller It is not append the window yet.

So you must call and use this method on `viewDidAppear` or connect to trigger like tap `button`  or etc.